# Copy specific files from one folder based on .csv

Tags: python, csv, copy

I have one folder with 8000 .txt files. I have a .csv file that lists 3000 of the filnames. I would like to copy these 3000 files to another folder. I tried the below:

```
import shutil
from csv import DictReader
from shutil import copyfile
import os


#src = "C:\Users\Desktop\Testsrc"
#dst = "C:\Users\Desktop\Testdir"

with open('Test.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
        filename = row['FilePath']
        print(row['FilePath'])
        shutil.copy(os.path.join('C:/Users/Desktop/Testsrc/', row), 'C:/Users/Desktop/Testdir/')
```

But I am getting the following error. Does someone have an idea how to fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Check\Copy.py", line 15, in <module>
    shutil.copy(os.path.join('C:/Users/Desktop/Testsrc/', row), 'C:/Users/Desktop/Testdir/')
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 117, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\genericpath.py", line 152, in _check_arg_types
    raise TypeError(f'{funcname}() argument must be str, bytes, or '
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'dict'
```

Comment: If you have your filepath in `row['FilePath']`, you need to you `row['FilePath']` or filename variable, not row, because the row is a dictionary with many fields

So use `shutil.copy(os.path.join('C:/Users/Desktop/Testsrc/', filename), 'C:/Users/Desktop/Testdir/')`

Comment: can you provide an example of the CSV file used? It's a bit hard to answer if we have to guess...  Also, magicarm22 provided the correct answer. Since you already assign the filepath to the variable `filename` you should use that instead of `row` in the `shutil.copy` line.